# Unit of Work - All Repositories need to be properties?

Tags: .net-core, repository, unit-of-work, ef-core-2.0

I am trying to use Repository/UoW Patternin a .net core project . I have looked at many implementations across web .  In all  the implementations repositories are created as properties in IUnitOfWork.

In Future if we have 50 Repositories we need to have 50 properties in the Unit of Work . Could anyone suggest a better approach for implementing Repository/UoW.

Please Find below the code snippets of approach i have implemented currently.

IUnitOfWork.cs

```
 IStudentRepository Student { get; set; }

        IClassRepository Class { get; set; }


        void Complete();
```

UnitOfWOrk.cs

```
public class unitofwork {

    private readonly CollegeContext _context;
            IStudentRepository Student { get; set; }

                IClassRepository Class { get; set; }
            public UnitOfWork(CollegeContext CollegeContext)
            {
                this._context = CollegeContext;
    Student =  new StudentRepository(_context);
    Class = new ClassRepository(_context);


            }

            public void Complete()
            {
                return _context.SaveChanges();
            }

}
```

Student and Class Repositories Inherit From a generic Repository class and IStudentRepository and IClassRepository respectively.

StudentRepository.cs

```
 public  class StudentRepository : Repository<Student>  , IStudentRepository
    {
        private readonly CollegeContext context;
        private DbSet<Student> entities;

        public StudentRepository(CollegeContext context) : base(context)
        {
            this.context = context;
            entities = context.Set<Student>();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Property-per-Repository is not convenient in some cases as you said. I generally use some sort of factory method in UoW class as below:

```
public class unitofwork
{

    private readonly CollegeContext _context;
    IStudentRepository Student { get; set; }

    IClassRepository Class { get; set; }
    public UnitOfWork(CollegeContext CollegeContext)
    {
        this._context = CollegeContext;
    }

    public T CreateRepository<T>() where T : IRepository
    {
        IRepository repository = null;
        if(typeof(T) == typeof(IStudentRepository))
            repository = new StudentRepository(_context);
        ......
        ......
        else
            throw new XyzException("Repository type is not handled.");

        return (T)repository;
    }

    public void Complete()
    {
        return _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}

public interface IRepository
{
    Guid RepositoryId { get; }
}
```

My `IRepository` just hold a simple property. You may extend this interface as per your needs.